# How can I troubleshoot email notifications from Stack Exchange sites not working?

Tags: support, notifications, email, comment-replies

I don't get email notifications when people reply to or comment on my questions on any Stack Exchange sites.  This behavior is consistent whether I have a Stack Exchange site open in one of my browser tabs or not.

I have tried the "once a day" and "every 3 hours" setting.  Neither of them work.  The emails are not in my spam or trash folder.  They are simply not being sent.

How do I troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: I think they only email you stuff you haven't seen, so if you are keeping up with your inbox I don't think you will recieve any emails.

Comment: This happens regardless of whether I have seen it or not.  The only way to get a notification is by opening the site in a browser.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the right mailbox?

Comment: Yes, I am checking the right mailbox.  My notifications are currently set to every 3 hours.  I close all tabs with SE sites and leave for a day.  I come back to SE and see a bunch of notifications about new answers to my questions but zero emails.  These notifications are broken, end of story.

Comment: I have the same problem, and am likewise not finding any way to debug this. I don't even know what such an email would look like to search for it.